# Save Video and Sequence of Images while recording video using Camera

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ipod

I need to save the video into a sequence of images while recording that video using the iphone/ipod camera and also I need to save that video. Please direct me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the following will help: [How to capture video frames from the camera as images using AV Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1702/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010192)

Comment: Thanks.. But I got the Solution in different way. Actually I need to show the video into frame by frame. So I used AVPlayer with manual controls.Which is now working fine.